# Enumerable.Last method

Tags: c#, enumerable

I am trying to print the both the value of .First and .Last but only the value of `.First()` comes up. `.Last()` just prints my "Text: " word and then blank.

I'v tried chainging the `i` to different values and that just makes the program worse.

```
case 2:
    Console.Write("\n\tType a word you want to search for: ");
    string sokord = Console.ReadLine();                           
    for (int i = 0; i < loggList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (loggList[i].First() == sokord)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\tTitel: " + loggList[i].First() + "\n\tText: " + loggList[i].Last());                                       
            break;
        }
    }
```

I want to get the titel from `.First()` and the text from `.Last()`.

Comment: What type is `loggList`?

Comment: It is a string List.

Comment: Are you changing the `List<string>` while you iterating over it? I mean, can this happen?

Comment: @ziNo, so `loggList[i]` is a `string`... and you want first and last letter/char ?

Comment: Seems like he is trying to find matching items > Change if (loggList[i].First() == sokord)  this to  if (loggList[i]== sokord)

Comment: @ziNo please show an example of what data you have as input in `loggList` and what data you want to be output. Right now, it is not clear what you want to happen.

Comment: I just lookup op "sokord", and translates to word/tag. So problably the OP wants to test on the first word. And print the first & last word, not the first and last characters.

Comment: Console.Write("\n\tPick a title: ");
                            loggArray = new string[3];
                            

                            loggArray[0] = Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("\n\Type your log: ");
                            loggArray[1] = Console.ReadLine();
                           
                            loggList.Add(loggArray)

Answer (score 0):

This is very difficult to guess at, since there isn't enough information about the type of loggList in the question.

I would probably write the code as follow though:

```
var firstMatch = loggList.FirstOrDefault(l => l.First() == sokord);
Console.WriteLine("\n\tTitel: " + firstMatch?.First() + "\n\tText: " + firstMatch?.Last());
```